# Contiki OS:Reading data from external motion sensor through I/O port in Sky mote

Tags: c, contiki

I am working on contiki os. I want to read sensor data that connected to Telosb mote through I/O port in contiki os.

I use the code (contiki-2.7/examples/ipv6/sky-websense.c). It read the data from the light and humidity sensors. But i want to read the data from external motion sensor that connected to sky mote

Looking forward for the reply

Thank you in advance

Comment: you want to read the data from the light and humidity external sensor, which are connected to sky mote. clarify.

Comment: I want to read data from external motion sensor that connected to sky mote.  Not light and humidity sensor..How it is possible.?

Answer (score 0):

In the below url they have discussed how to read the data from the external sensor with an example.
http://www.advanticsys.com/shop/documents/1351090495_DS1000_contiki2.6.zip
Can you pl. check test-DSC1000.c file for reading the data from sensor,to check if it helps you.